# opendaylight bundle:stop doesn't work in the way as I expect

Tags: osgi, opendaylight

I am new to the opendaylight. The question is that I tried to use "bundle:stop" to stop a bundle which status was successfully changed from "Active" to "Resolved". However, this bundle has some rpc methods which are still able to handle requests after that.

So I am just curious what's the correct understanding of "bundle:stop" or the reason why this could happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping a bundle just means that its blueprint context is closed and if present the stop method of the Activator is called. The developer of the bundle is reponsible to make sure all activities of the bundle are shut down when this happens.

So for example if you start a REST service in the start method of an Activator but do not shut it down in the stop method then it will continue to run. So this might be an error in the bundle.

Comment: You are right. I will double check the bundle code. Thanks!